# Proof verification: The adjoint representation of a Lie group is smooth

Tags: solution-verification, lie-groups

I wonder if anyone can help me verify that my proof for showing the adjoint representation of a Lie group is smooth?

I know that there are some other posts proving smoothness using the exponential map.
I want to know if my proof which does not use exponential map makes sense.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Which part(s) do you really have problem with?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for your comment! It's about the last paragraph in the picture. I am just not feeling sure about it.

For example, in the last two sentences, does "when $e$ is fixed, entries of $(dF)_{(g, e)}$ depend smoothly on $g$, ..., so entries of $(d\Psi_g)_e$ depend smoothly on $g$" make sense to you?

Comment: Show that the assignment $g\longrightarrow \text{Ad}_{g}(v)$ is smooth for all $v\in\mathfrak{g}$ and you are done. In particular, the global differentials are smooth maps to the various tangent bundles.

Comment: To be more clear, you want to show that this assignment is smooth for all $v$, because then in a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$, you have that $\text{Ad}_g(v)$ is a smooth matrix representation, with column vectors $\text{Ad}_g(e_i)$. You don't need to go into charts to do this i believe.